# update.packages() claims to update old packages but does not install newest version

Tags: r, package

I attempted to update all packages that I have to the newest version. I first checked which packages are not up to date with `old.packages()`. This showed me that the packages backports, Matrix and Tibble are not up to date. When I ran `update.packages()`, the console showed me that exactly those packages are being updated. However, running `old.packages()` again showed me that these three packages are not up to date. What am I not getting?

Kind regards

Comment: Did you restart R after installing the new packages, before checking `old.packages()`?

Comment: Yes, I checked that now. I restarted R studio if you mean that. I also tried to use ```command/ctrl + shift + F10 ``` to restart R. This also did not change anything.

Comment: what is `.libPaths()` ? You might be updating them in one location and loading them from another ... ?

Comment: ```.libPaths()``` defaults to the library folder in my home directory. This is where I store all my packages. I guess this should not be a problem then, right?